# Searching hundreds of org-mode files without loading them into Emacs?

Tags: search, emacs, org-mode

I've compiled hundres of org-mode files in a specific directory.

Is there any way to search these files for specific keywords, or build agendas,
without loading them into Emacs, possibly using external search tools such as `ag'?

Comment: Search with `rgrep`. And my guess is that only org-mode knows about org-mode agendas.

Answer (score 1):

You can search them using [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles). In *Icicle* minor mode, `C-x C-f` is bound to a [multi-completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#SecondExampleMultiCompletion) command that lets you match against the file name or the file content, or both.  You can change the match patterns on the fly.  Buffer `*Completions*` shows you the files that match.

And you can use [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion), combining any number of search patterns.  Each pattern can itself be a regexp (or a substring), but it is a lot easier to combine several simple patterns than it is to come up with one complex pattern to DTRT. You can also [negate](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets#icicle-candidate-set-complement) patterns (obtain the complement of the match set).

You can visit any of the matching files that you like -- any number of them during the same command invocation.  Or you can visit none of them if you like (`C-g`), and just use the command to locate those that match.  You can use `C-M-RET`, `C-M-down`, etc. to get information about particular matching files (file type, permissions, size, last access time, creation time, etc.).

You can *act* on any number of them in some other way than visiting, using an alternate function that you specify: Just bind variable `icicle-candidate-alt-action-fn` to this function in a command you write that invokes `icicle-find-file-of-content`. Lots more features --- see [Icicles - File-Name Input](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input).